# How to detect click on the images in phaser3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am new to phaser and I am trying to detect a click on several images in phaser3 .This has somehow become a two part problem for me.
First is to detect click on the objects, but even if I click anywhere else on the screen also the click handler fires.

Second part is that I have identical and multiple images on the scene, and I want to detect clicks on each of them inside a single function only and detect which image was clicked .

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.24.1/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
    <style media="screen">
      canvas {   display : block;   margin : auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    var config = {
        type: Phaser.CANVAS,
        scale: {
            mode: Phaser.Scale.ScaleModes.FIT,
            parent: 'phaser-example',
            autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
            width: 400,
            height: 640
        },
        // width: 400,
        // height: 640,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: { y: 10 }
            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
    var Bimages;

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.setBaseURL('http://localhost:3000');
            
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/skies/deepblue.png');
        this.load.image('tube1', 'assets/myassets/ballSort/tube.png');
        this.load.image('tube2', 'assets/myassets/ballSort/tube.png');
    }

    var numOfTestTubes = 5;

    var storeTubes = [];

    function create ()
    {
        ctx = this;
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky').scaleY = 1.2;
        var t1 = ctx.add.image(150, 300, 'tube1');
        t1.scaleY = 0.5;
        t1.scaleX = 0.5;
        var t2 = ctx.add.image(220, 300, 'tube2');
        t2.scaleY = 0.5;
        t2.scaleX = 0.5;

        t1.setInteractive();
        t2.setInteractive();

        t1.on('pointerdown', handleclick);
    }

    function update(){
    }

    function handleclick(pointer, targets){
      console.log("clicked0",pointer);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me out here please?

Answer (score 4):

The pointerdown event listener on game objects is different than the pointerdown event listener on the global input manager. If you instead do `this.input.on('pointerdown', ...)` you'll get a callback with the pointer, but also an array of game objects that were clicked, with an empty array if no game objects were clicked. If you need to register clicks on input objects that overlap each other, you can change this behavior with #setTopOnly. You can check object equality or against some property expected such as the object's name or texture key. I linked a stackblitz with rectangles, but understand they are behaving the same as an image's hitbox would.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/phaser-so-global-input-manager?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run something when just clicked, instead of pointer up or pointer down, try the following workaround like this.

```
this.add.text(100, 200, 'Click me', { fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 64, color: '#00ff00' }).setInteractive({ draggable: true });

this.input.on('dragend', (pointer, object) =>{
    if(pointer.x==object.input.dragStartXGlobal &&
        pointer.y==object.input.dragStartYGlobal){
        alert("Object clicked");
    }
});
```